# Language laravel settings

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am sitting with an odd problem. 
I bet that the answer is really simple, but somehow I can't find it.

I created a new language file in

```
--resources
  --lang
    --en
    --jp
```

Now the meaning is to start using Japanese as the main language of the application. It doesn't need to be multilanguage.

I only want to use Japanese.

I changed the language in the config/app file to "jp".
As I read on the internet, this should do the trick.

It doesn't work. 
Am I wrong here?

When I ask laravel what language it is using with

```
$locale = App::getLocale()
```

I keep getting "en", but in the config is standing "jp".

How can I tell the framework to always only use the jp part?

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem!

This command

```
php artisan config:clear
```

did the trick!